# Non-rotating background image on orientation change on iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, device-orientation

I'm developing an iphone app and it allows for both portrait and landscape orientation. However, I have a background image, in an UIImageView, which should not be rotated when the orientation changes. I've searched around and experimented with some options, but have not found a satisfactory solution. I tried using transforms in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: but it makes the image move during rotation, and doesn't look good. I would like it to remain stationary.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
YourAppDelegate *appDel = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDel.window insertSubview:yourImageView atIndex:appropriateIndex];
```

as your appDelegate.window doesn't care about the current device orientation it might work out as a solution. I just tried adding a UIImageView to the appDel.window in the

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

method, and as expected, it does not rotate with the above uiviewcontroller.view

Of course you could also try addSubview: